# How to prevent os.popen from returning output?

Tags: python

I'm writing a command to cmd via os.popen, but the result of this command is unending 'rubbish' that I'm not interested in. I just need to run the command and I don't want anything back.

PS: any other solutions using os.system or subprocess module are accepted. But keep in mind that the command will keep that cmd terminal busy forever, it is endless. I just want to run it from my main program and move on to my other stuff, not wait for outputs, and I don't want to see outputs in the first place.

EDIT: People ask for actual code:

```
os.popen(f'tensorboard --logdir="{path + logdir}" --host localhost --port {pn}', 'w')
```

Comment: Does it return something like this `<os._wrap_close object at 0x7f8aef0924e0>
`?

Comment: How is it returning the output to your script? If it's returning something, just don't print the result.

Comment: @0xPrateek yes!

Comment: Please show your actual code

Comment: @Barmar I'm not printing anything, wiritings from that cmd keeps popping up in my console after I run that command.

Comment: That's not output, that's the object used to represent the stream that you can read or write.

Comment: @Barmar I added the code

Comment: If you use `w` mode, it means that you can write to the object, and it will become input to the command. Any output from the command will be written to the terminal.

Comment: Use `r` mode if you want the output to be written to the pipe instead of the terminal.

Comment: @Barmar I did it. It is the default by the way. Same thing.

Comment: Try using `subprocess.run()` instead of `os.popen()`.

Comment: @Barmar subprocess.run is bad. It waits for that command to be executed, but that command is endless. I just want it to run and I move one to my other stuff not wait

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

def runCmd(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    output = p.communicate()
    assert(output[0] is None)

runCmd(['ls', '-l'])
```

The above function `runCmd` will run a command, cmd,an array of arguments.

Comment: No, this is very bad. It forces my main program to wait for the output. The output is endless, I just want to run it and move on to my other stuff, not waiting for endless outputs. I just tried it.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Not it is not. Please read my comment to his answer.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy what do you mean?

Comment: I now open with `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL' and there is no output created.

Comment: @Alex Deft: I shouldn't be so presumptuous as to answer for GreenCloakGuy, but I believe what he meant is that if you do not want to wait for endless output, you could be running that work in another thread or process and continuing on with other work in your main thread. Even if you suppress all output, the command you are running will be attempting to generate the output anyway and you will not necessarily be decreasing the running time significantly.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Very good point. Yes, you're right. But, I'm tired of doing it. I'm running tons of experiments and I'm sick of openinging new terminals and typing this stuff in it. That's what I'm doing now, but I plan to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun function that will execute *any* other function you give it, with the given `args` and `kwargs`, and will turn off standard output and standard error before running said function and turn them back on afterwards.

```
def call_quiet(func, *args, **kwargs):
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
        sys.stdout, sys.stderr = devnull, devnull
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            sys.stdout, sys.stderr = sys.__stdout__, sys.__stderr__
```

Example usage:

```
call_quiet(os.popen, f'tensorboard --logdir="{path + logdir}" --host localhost --port {pn}', 'w')
```

Comment: I tried it. It works, but, same thing, it returns tons of  stuff like this:
I0625 07:37:20.008877 13116 _internal.py:122] 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2019 07:37:20] "GET /data/experiments HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: If it's that type of output, it might actually not be possible to suppress it via python - the subprocess might just access system-stdout on its own somehow. Since you're using a subprocess/popen anyway, have you investigated the possible existence of a `--quiet` command-line option, or something similar?

Comment: This seems promising solution. I did some search but it is way above my head.

Comment: I did it! I added those two flags to the end of my command >nul 2>&1. They supressed the output for EVER. Thank you.  Genuis solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @green_cloak_guy's response, you can use [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) to manage the swapping for you with a little less boiileplate:

[EDIT: add redirect_stderr as well. Not sure if there is a better way to bundle both]

```
import contextlib
import os

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open(os.devnull, 'w')):
    with contextlib.redirect_stderr(open(os.devnull, 'w')):
        os.popen('...')
```

Comment: It works, but, same same, tons of rubbish  show up like this:
I0625 07:40:44.454461 12164 _internal.py:122] 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2019 07:40:44] "GET /data/runs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0625 07:40:44.459447 20224 _internal.py:122] 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2019 07:40:44] "GET /data/experiments HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Try also adding a `redirect_stderr` block. Updating comment to include...

Comment: I put this context manager around my `subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)' solution and it had no effect in Windows or the Git Bash environment that comes with Windows Git. And I just now tried it in Linux to no effect. ???

Comment: Interesting, the stdout arg must take precedence and results in an output stream not touched by the context manager. @Alex I added the block above, or you could go with Ronald's solution below (might also need an stderr input arg)

Comment: I tried you update it is the same unforturantely. My command is tensorboard, you can try it if you can. It return lots of lines. Could it be because of IPython console in Pycharm?